# Using DateTimeKind on DateTime triggers V3058

Tags: pvs-studio

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>()
{
    [new DateTime(0, DateTimeKind.Utc)] = 0,
    [new DateTime(1, DateTimeKind.Utc)] = 1
}
```

`dict1` triggers V3058 "V3058 An item with the same key '1' has already been added.".

https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V3058/ states that it warns about issues, that will cause an ArgumentException.
This is clearly not the case here as the keys are different.

Leaving out `DateTimeKind.UTC` from the ctors stops triggering V3058.

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>()
{
    [new DateTime(0)] = 0,
    [new DateTime(1)] = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback! We will fix the issue and let you know about the results. PVS-Studio Team.

Comment: Hi again! 
We've fixed the problem. The changes will be available in the next release. Follow the updates on the [site](https://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio-download/).
PVS-Studio Team.